# Changing default location map shows

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I have a website template that I want to use. The template has a map on one of the pages and I'd like to use the map but change the location of where the map shows.

In the .html file it has the following line of code

```
<div id="gmap"></div>
```

And then in the js folder the file

> gmap3.min.js

Has the following code

http://pastebin.com/tRLsiy7D

**How can I change the location the map shows?**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the markers then you can change the position like

```
$('.gmap3.top').gmap3({
 marker:{
    latLng:[29.132318972825445,81.32052349999992]
 }
});
```

or if you want to change the center position of Google Maps and Marker

```
$('#gmap').gmap3({
 map:{
    options:{
     center: [-33, 151], //---place the lat and lon of map's center position
     zoom: 8
    }
 },
 marker:{
    latLng: [-33, 151],  //---place the lat and lon of marker
    callback: function(){
     //----
    }
 }
});
```

For information, check this [**documentation**](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/5-getting-started)

Comment: Do I do this in the .html file or in the js file?

Comment: I added both parts (one t a time) after the line that I showed in the original post but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but i came across the same issue and found a way to solve it.

The Javascript on the gmap3.js or map3.min.js is configured to get the position for the marker from the address while all other values are set to false, including LatLng, as we can see in the piece of code from gmap3.js:

```
    latLng:{
      map:false, 
      marker:false, 
      infowindow:false, 
      circle:false, 
      overlay: false,
      getlatlng: false,
      getmaxzoom: false,
      getelevation: false,
      streetviewpanorama: false,
      getaddress: true
    },
```

On most templates the address is located on a script at the end of the HTML file, on the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gmap").gmap3({ ... }
```

Simply change the adress located in that function and the location of your marker should change.